# Vue prerender flickering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, prerender

I have the following solution now:

```
<template>
    <section id="prod-main">
        <prod-preview v-for="prod in products" :id="prod.id" :key="prod.id"/>
    </section>
</template>

export default {
...
    computed: {
        products: function () {
            return this.$store.getters['products/getPreview']
        }
    }
...
}
```

Vuex store will receive info after some delay from my backend. So at first call it will be empty. Now I want to use vue spa prerender and here I see a flickering.
As I understood it works like:
1. Browser loads HTML with products
2. Execute js that replace products with nothing because the store is empty.
3. After some delay shows it again with backend info.

How can I fix it? I should left prerender for indexing and I can't hardcode the backend reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setting `captureAfterTime` to wait for your async call to complete, before saving the html of the page.

Other settings are available :

```
    // NOTE: Unless you are relying on asynchronously rendered content,
    // such as after an Ajax request, none of these options should be
    // necessary. All synchronous scripts are already executed before
    // capturing the page content.

    // Wait until a specific event is fired on the document.
    captureAfterDocumentEvent: 'custom-post-render-event',
    // This is how you would trigger this example event:
    // document.dispatchEvent(new Event('custom-post-render-event'))

    // Wait until a specific element is detected with
    // document.querySelector.
    captureAfterElementExists: '#content',

    // Wait until a number of milliseconds has passed after scripts
    // have been executed. It's important to note that this may
    // produce unreliable results when relying on network
    // communication or other operations with highly variable timing.
    captureAfterTime: 5000,
```

---

Another issue can be related to how the prerendered HTMl gets hydrated, i've openned an issue on github, but they still haven't addressed it (and are not willing to ?) 
https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/issues/131

The solution is to add `data-server-rendered="true"` to your vuejs parent node in the prerendered html, like this:
`<div id="root" data-server-rendered="true">...`

You can use the option `postProcessHtml` to do so.

Comment: Vue spa plugins work well. Prerendered HTML is fine. The main trouble that js hides prerendered HTML until I receive data from the backend. So you will see prerendered products, after nothing and finally data from the backend. This will cause the flickering.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer. Add `data-server-rendered="true"` to the prerendered html.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I found a solution that fit my requirements from your link. Now I mount vue only after I have received all info from my backend. And all working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your problem here but have you tried to add a `v-if` to avoid flickering:

```
<template>
    <section id="prod-main">
        <prod-preview
            v-if="products.length > 0" 
            v-for="prod in products" 
            :id="prod.id" 
            :key="prod.id"/>
    </section>
</template>
```